# In grid with forceFit: true on first display of hidden column all columns shrink to the left

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**Problem**:

On first display of grid hidden column all columns shrink to the left, check attached image. If I show, hide and show this column again all works just fine No matter how many hidden columns in my grid, on first display of each of the hidden columns described issue will appear.

Before: [image]

After: [image]

**Description**:

In my app I have a grid with dynamic data and I reconfigure it on its store `metachange` event, like this:

```
Ext.define('Portal.store.DynamicStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    ...

    constructor: function (config) {
        if (config) {
            Ext.apply(this, {

                ...

                listeners: {
                    metachange: function (store, meta) {
                        if (config.grid) {
                            config.grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Worth mention that if I create simple grid with hidden columns and store with local data all works just fine.

I created a [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1266) to illustrate described issue.

And this is my [actual code](http://paste2.org/HUhGfxEp).

Seems that its known bug with grid `forceFit: true` and hidden columns.
Here is [bug report](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261682-Bug-grid-render-with-hidden-column-and-forcefit-true) on sencha forum.

Any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Are you using a different version locally than the one used in the fiddle? Do you have local overrides? If you can't reproduce the issue in the fiddle it's probably something local.

Comment: Nope, I use exactly 4.2.0.663. No local overrides for grid. I can bet that its because I configure grid columns property on fly and grid layout somehow calculated incorrectly. However, if I call `doComponentLayout()` after `reconfigure()` it doesnt help.

Comment: Can you update your fiddle to look exactly like it does on your project? Same initialization and listeners?

Comment: I tried for an hour to configure fiddle to reflect my real code but I guess its easier to just post it - http://paste2.org/HUhGfxEp